# able to view data saved using cloudkit from cloudkit dashboard but cannot view it in icloud drive

Tags: ios, xcode, cloudkit

I am able to save and view data using cloudkit framework from cloudkit dashboard but why I am not able to view the same data in the icloud drive since I think that data is being saved in the icloud drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudKit functions very much like a key-value NoSQL persistence layer. The data stored there can only be interacted with from the CloudKit Dashboard and through the CloudKit APIs (like your app uses).

Data stored using CloudKit is **not** accessible through iCloud Drive.

In order to access information in iCloud Drive, you will have to store your data differently.

Check out the [iCloud Fundamentals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html) for further information on iCloud document storage.